# Hyper-v Open Virtual Machine

Tags: hyper-v

After rebooting is it possible to open a Hyper-V virtual machine without going through the Manager?  It seems like it is already running in the background or maybe it is just in its last state.

Answer (score 0):

If the OS in the Hyper-V virtual allows for remoting and *also* it is on the same network as the attempt to open a remote desktop to that virtual.

Note that the default network adapter for a virtual will provide a different IP address than what the local network provides to the server. You will most likely want to create a network adapter (in Hyper-V) which shares the network card to the virtual and the virtual will get its IP address from the local network.

If you can ping it, then it can be remoted to..but other things within the virtual has to allow for remoting.

---

Upon reading the OPs comments, it is clear that the need is to launch the virtual outside of Hyper-V. Hyper-V uses `VMConnect.exe` to achieve that...and that is available.

One can do that in an elevated Powershell shell such as:

```
vmconnect {Local/remote computer name} {Virtual Name}
```

such as

```
vmconnect Hyperion W10-Zephyr
```

where `Hyperion` is the local computer name and `W10-Zephyr` is the virtual's name.

See also [Connecting to Hyper-V virtual machines with PowerShell](https://www.powershellmagazine.com/2012/10/11/connecting-to-hyper-v-virtual-machines-with-powershell/)

Comment: Not even that complicated.  I use two programs that are not compatible with each other.  I am using Hyper-V to provide a Windows 10 virtual machine so I can keep them isolated.  I just want a way to directly open the virtual machine.

Comment: I am not seeing what you mean by `open the virtual machine`...you want to connect to it after a reboot? If not by remote desktop, then by explorer? The virtuals are simply machines on a network. If you ran one of the programs on a laptop on your network, how would you access it from another machine? Its the same with running virtuals.

Comment: Right now I have a button on my desk top that open Hyper-V Manager.  After it opens I have to double click on the virtual machine.  I am lazy.  I want a single command I can but on the desk top that will open the virtual machine directly after booting the computer.  I do not want to have to go threw Hyper-V Manager.

Comment: Ah...why didn't you say that. ;-) See my update. Note you will most likely have to create a cmd shortcut on the desktop to get a one-click like functionality.